# Fixed width on mobile does not work

Tags: html, css, dom

**EDIT FOR SOLUTION FOR MY ISSUE:**

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -.2px;
    font-kerning: normal;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.wrapperAudit {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #cbdcc6;
    min-width: 991px;
}
```

**-----------------------------END OF EDIT---------------------------------**

I'm using a wrapper div to make full page background image on my website and I want to make fixed wrapper div width like;

`min-width:991px;`

It works well if I open it on pc and it works well when I resize it below 991px as well.

[image]

But when I open the website on mobile device, it looks like that:

[image]

Could you please explain to me what is wrong here ?

Here is my code:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    letter-spacing: -.2px;
    font-kerning: normal;
}
.wrapper{
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #cbdcc6;
    min-width: 991px;
}
```

Comment: min-windth doesn't mean is fixed.

Comment: add this on in body {
  min-width:1050px;
}

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Are you wondering why the .wrapper div (green in your screenshot) is not expanding the entire height of the mobile view port (white in your screenshot)?

Comment: I had forgotten to add '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">', Right now green side is ok, but white side is still there

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it to look for a mobile

include the viewport meta tag at the top of your HTML

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design?hl=en

Comment: I had written "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width>", thank you. But I have smilar problem right now, there is still white space If I scroll down

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make the `wrapper` a `fixed` div that covers the page?

For example, inside your page's `body`, have a

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

And in your CSS,

```
#wrapper
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -99999;
  background-color: green; /* modify this to suit you */
}
```

The `z-index: -99999` is to make sure the background stays under all other elements. Just make sure this value is less than the `z-index` values of all other elements in your page.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guy5mmbn/1/). Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this solition didn't work. Actually I'm using a background image instead of background-color, and If I use position fixed to wrapper, I can't scroll it left or right although it contains content

Comment: It'll work for `background-image`s too. If you want a scrollable wrapper, then just use another div for showing the background. Take a look at the JSFiddle in the answer. For a demo of using a background image, and scrollable wrapper, see this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guy5mmbn/5/

Comment: I think I has explained wrongly my problem, I don't need a fixed background. I just needed to make fixed wrapper width to block scale website below 991px, but if I do this "min-height:991px" it behaves like that so white spaces happen, thank you so much for your interest again I hope I can find a solution or maybe I can try to change my codes

Answer (score 0):

It would make more sense to just have a fixed div as CEP said. An alternative to his answer would be to use 100% of the viewers height and width by using the VH and VW units.

html

```
<div id="bground"></div>

<div id="first-div">
Hi, I'm a preety cool div who can't spell!
</div>
```

css

```
#bground
{
  background-color: green;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

#first-div
{
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sLm1k410/